# django and apache: get traceback of 403 Forbidden

Tags: django, apache, http-status-code-403, traceback

I am developing a web app with Django and apache.
I can access the homepage but when I log in I get `403 Forbidden`.
Where can I get a traceback of the error so I can solve the problem?

I am developing in local so I set `DEBUG=True`.
Here is what I see in the apache log:

```
[Tue Mar 24 14:12:13.230364 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3738:tid 139683667068800] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Tue Mar 24 14:12:13.338989 2015] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3738:tid 139683667068800] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 24 14:12:13.339010 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3738:tid 139683667068800] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

No trace of the mistake!

**EDIT** :
It doesn't seem to be an apache error, I have the same problem using the django local server:

```
24/Mar/2015 15:51:28] "POST /accounts/participant_login/?next=/participants/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6286
[24/Mar/2015 15:51:41] "POST /accounts/participant_login/?next=/participants/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[24/Mar/2015 15:51:41] "GET /participants/ HTTP/1.1" 403 22
```

Comment: You should use try/except and log the exceptions to catch errors that are not reported. Anyway, if you have that error when you're trying to login, it seems to me that your form does not have the csrf token and you've got a forbidden request.

Comment: I used a log in the view and it's not called. I don't think it is related to csrf token, it works well on production server and I didn't change the code, just updated settings.py and apache configuration file.

Comment: Are you using an sqlite database locally and MySql/Postgres on production? If so, you want to give "www-data" permission to write in the database. If none of the above, I would advice you to use Pycharm editor (or any with debugger) and use its amazing Debug Tools when running locally, testing it on Apache locally and pass it to production. Otherwise you'll end up having a lot of this problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you can check the error under the `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Another (less recommended) solution is to set the `DEBUG` variable to `True`.

Comment: Does the login work when you run the development server rather than with Apache?

Comment: It works well on the production server but not on my local server (with Apache). I didn't change the code, just updated settings.py and apache configuration file.

Comment: I have the same problem when I use the django server! :(

Comment: Lol, I think I've never come to this with development server. Do you have a `raise PermissionDenied()` somewhere? Are you trying to log in with a superuser or just staff?

Comment: You were right! I had a `PermissionDenied` with a user that was not active (I deactivated his account in the database just before, for testing purpose). Solved! Thanks.

Comment: Nice! glad it helped =)